# Display User Profile Picture From Microsoft Graph using OAuth

Tags: flask, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

Could do with some help with the following: I'm Trying to Display the profile picture of a giving User who is after logging into my Flask Application: at the moment; I have the following:

```
photo = microsoft.get('me/photo/$value')
    print(photo)
```

When i print the photo object I'm getting back the OAuthResponse:

```
<flask_oauthlib.client.OAuthResponse object at 0x00>
```

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint returns binary data which you can simply write in disk

```
filename = 'some_image.jpg'  # I assume you have a way of picking unique filenames
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(microsoft.get("me/photo/$value").data)
```

This will create an image with filename **some_image.jpg**